# link_to new with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a link that pass a parameter, so I don't have to ask it in the form.

Something like this :

```
<%= button_to "New", new_skill_path(:controller => "skills",:action => "new", :request => "true") %>
```

I can show that the parameter is taken… but on my view, The `<%= f.text_field :request %>` is not "true" ?

(idem if I add :post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to don't use @request because Rails Use the request method, and I prefer to use link_to instead of button_to, anyway you will send your data by get method.

Views

```
<%= link_to("New", "/skills/new?val=true")  %>
```

or  ...... I think this one is much better

```
<%= link_to "New",new_skill_path+"?val=true" %>
```

Controller

```
@val = true if params[:val] == "true"
```

Comment: This seems slightly less DRY than it should be because if the route to the skills controller is changed you'll have to manually change the specified path in the `link_to` call.  How can we leverage the path helpers already available?